# Java - Factor Generator program nextfactor method

Tags: java

I've been trying to modify the nextfactor method for a while now to get the desired result. Basically, I'm supposed to  exclude all even numbers, except for 2 but am still unable to do it. The code for the class is below. Any help is appreciated. Regards

```
public class FactorGenerator
{
   private int number;

   public FactorGenerator(int num)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    number = num;
    if (number <= 2) {
        System.out.println("Wrong argument");
    }
}

   public boolean hasMoreFactors()
{
    if (number >= 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // return (number >= 2);
}

   public boolean isDivisible(int otherNumber)
{
    if (number % otherNumber == 0) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Determine next factor.
 * pre-condition: call only if hasMoreFactors 
 * returns true
 * 
 * @return a factor of the object's number
 */
public int nextFactor()
{
    int triedFactor = 2;

 if(number % nextFactor == 0)

    while (! isDivisible(triedFactor)) {
        triedFactor = triedFactor+1;
    }
    number = number / triedFactor;
    return triedFactor;
}
        }
```

Comment: Pls, stop obfuscating the program by constructions like `if (x) return true; else return false;`. Something like  `triedFactor = triedFactor==2 ? 3 : triedFactor+2;` solves your problem, but the program stays terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
triedFactor = triedFactor==2 ? 3 : triedFactor+2;
```

instead of

```
triedFactor = triedFactor+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (! isDivisible(triedFactor)) {
    if(triedFactor == 2) {
      triedFactor = triedFactor+1;
    } else {
      triedFactor = triedFactor+2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Exclude all even except 2 ? This is code

public ArrayList GetExeptEven(int upperBound){
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    for(int i=3;i<=upperBound;i=i+2)
    list.add(i);

    return list;
    }
```

Comment: we're only supposed to modify the method. Nothing else.

Comment: A few more issues with your piece of code (apart from the fact that it's not what the op asked for):
- You don't have any error checks. What happens if upperBound is 1? You return [1,2] whereas it should have been [1]. Also, what about 0 or negative numbers??? You also return [1,2] where you should have thrown an IllegalArgumentException.
- When you're using collections, it would be nice if you would also use generics, and it's always better to use interfaces instead of concrete implementations:
public List<Integer> Ge... {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(1);
...
}